# Is it posisble to have multiple obejcts in focus provided that parallel ligthrays pass through them?

Tags: optics, imaging

I have the following setup, with a light source, 4 mirrors (two concave and two flat) and a 200mm lens, plus a divergent lens.

[image]

In the parallel section of the flow, I have a translucent background (in cyan) and an object (in pink). My idea wast that as the light rays passing through both objects are parallel, I should be able to get them both in focus (which is my main goal), by focusing correctly with the lens, however my tests suggest that this is not true.

My questions would be the following:

- Why is it not possible to have both objects in focus with this setup, can you explain it with geometrical optics?
- Can you suggest another way to have both objects in focus at the same time? Having a large enough depth of field depth is not sufficient for me (I want both objects to be perfectly in focus on the one hand, and on the other hand, the distance between them is quite big, around 70 cm)

Additionally, any books/sources you can recommend on imaging of lens and ray tracing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The only way to get two things at different locations in focus on an image, is if you create an imaging setup that will create a real image of your first object in the same plane as the second object. Then, when imaging the plane that contains both the real image of the first object and the second object, both will appear in focus. But I must say that it will be an awkward image, like a fake background. It will also create more geometrical constraints for the whole optical train/imaged planes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Focus" isn't defined as "all the light rays from this object are one single point on my camera." It's defined as "one point from this object is a single point on my camera." So your green LED, which is one point, and is one point on the camera, is in focus in this picture. Many points on the purple ball map to the same point in the camera, so it's not in focus in the sense that photographers mean (you get an unblurred image of the ball). To see whether the purple ball would look focused in your image, you should consider light rays from one point on the purple ball but launched at different angles. See if they end up in the same spot on the camera (the same way you did for the LED)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is also what I had in mind. When I place a sheet of paper in the light path, the contour of this ball is sharp, regardless of where I put it: what is reason for having a shape contour on the paper, but not on the camera sensor?

Comment: Yeah... that's true. And I can see how that might make you think it was "focused" in some sense. I think the resolution is that this only happens because it's being illuminated from behind by perfectly parallel light rays - which is not normally how we illuminate things. If you illuminate the ball from in front with a light bulb, then put a camera sensor somewhere along this path without any lens in front of it (like between the second flat mirror and the second concave mirror), you definitely won't see an image of a ball appear on the sensor.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your idea is that the light emitted/reflected/scattered from the cyan and pink objects is not parallel.

[image]

The optical arrangement is such that the green led $g$ at the focal point of the first concave mirror produces light which forms an intermediate image $g'$ at the focal point of the second concave mirror which in turn forms an image $g''$ at the camera.

Light emitted/reflected/scattered from the cyan and pink objects is not parallel and after reelection from the concave mirror intermediate images are formed at $c'$ and $p'$.
Because these images are not located at $g'$ they will not form an image at the camera $g''$ but somewhere "behind" the camera and so will not form a sharp image at coincident with image $g''$.

Comment: Thank you for the response Farcher! Do you have any suggestions for having both objects in focus? Also, as I asked from Andrew: When I place a sheet of paper in the light path, the contour of this ball is sharp, regardless of where I put it: what is reason for having a shape contour on the paper, but not on the camera sensor?

Comment: The sharp contour is possibly the shadow of the ball?

Comment: You need to have a look at an arrangement with a large [depth of field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field)?